# how can i install Mysql alongside MariaDB without losing my data?

Tags: mysql, database, snort

I am trying to install snort, barnyard2 and base that uses Mysql in the same machine where is MISP (platform sharing information) installed and that uses the MariaDB database.

I do the following steps :

1- Installing misp with mariaDB database

2- Installing snort

3- when I try installing mysql to use Barnyard2 and base my first database is dropped and all the data is lost and misp is no longer working.

I am new to cybersecurity, is there anyway I can install an ids alongside with the misp platform? Any help please

Comment: You already have MariaDB, why don't you just use that?

Comment: Coexistence requires separate directory trees, separate my.cnf, separate port number.  Using Docker is also quite viable (it forces all of the above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not install MySQL. You need to create a database for SNORT in your MariaDB and configure barnyard2 to use that database.

So, you need to do only steps 1 and 2, not step 3.

Comment: Can you tell me please where do I need to change the database used for barnyar2, because when I try installing it without installing mysql it generate an error : mysql.h not found

Comment: This step is about compiling barnyard2, it needs the `mysql.h` include file in order to use MySQL client libraries. You don't need to change that at all, you need to compile barnyard2 correctly and then change its configuration. If you are using some installer package that installs MySQL server in addition to barnyard2, you need to look into way without installing MySQL server.